# Error Code: 1206. The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size

Tags: mysql, sql

I am deleting 1000 records in single shot from some millions of records.  It is going well, when i start the process.

Lets assume table has 4000000 records and from this I want to delete 22002. So here 22000 is going well.  Because my delete query has limit 1000.  So once it touches 1000, it stops traversing.  But for last 2 record it traversing till end of table, so I am getting above mentioned error.

May I get any help on this.

I have verified my.config file, there I have innodb_buffer_pool_size=107M.

Comment: Do you know the settings to `innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size` and `innodb_buffer_pool_instances` ?

Comment: @PaulT. Thanks!! Actually my problem is resolved by just changing  innodb_buffer_pool_size to 256M